# Cannot Update State with Form onSubmit React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component with a list of components. I have an initial cardlist which gets populated as the list in my component. Each time I submit the form I want to add a new component, but I can't get it to update even though my cardlist array gets a new card. What do I do?

```
import { Card } from "./Card";

export function Body() {
    let imgname = "";
    let imgurl = "";

    let cardlist = [
        {
            name: "ca122t1",
            url: "https://img.webmd.com/dtmcms/live/webmd/consumer_assets/site_images/article_thumbnails/other/cat_relaxing_on_patio_other/1800x1200_cat_relaxing_on_patio_other.jpg"
        },
        {
            name: "cat2",
            url: "https://img.webmd.com/dtmcms/live/webmd/consumer_assets/site_images/article_thumbnails/other/cat_relaxing_on_patio_other/1800x1200_cat_relaxing_on_patio_other.jpg"
        }
    ]
    const [list, setList] = React.useState(cardlist);
    
    
    function handleName(event) {
        imgname = event.target.value;
    }

    function handleURL(event) {
        imgurl = event.target.value;
    }

    function handleSubmit(e) {
        let imgToAdd = {name: imgname, url: imgurl}
        cardlist.push(imgToAdd)
        setList(cardlist)
        e.preventDefault()
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <label>Name</label>
                <input type="text" onChange={handleName}/>
                <label>Image URL</label>
                <input type="text" onChange={handleURL}/>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
            </form>
            <ul>
                {list.map((item) => (
                    <Card name={item.name} url={item.url}></Card>
                ))}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Never modify state in React directly. Instead, copy the values of the old array into a new one. Also, you should use the old state (`list`) and not your `cardlist` variable which is just used for initializing the state.
In ES6 you can simply do

```
function handleSubmit(e) {
  // copy the elements of list into a new array and add the new card
  setList([...list, {name: imgname, url: imgurl}]);
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

EDIT:
I just saw that you are also not using state for the `imgname` and `imgurl` variable, so this answer should work but fill in empty strings for the new values. Everything that changes in a component should `useState`:

```
const [imgname, setImgname] = useState("");
function handleName(event){
  setImgname(event.target.value)
}
```

Also, for controlled inputs, set the value from state to avoid inconsistencies:

```
<input type="text" onChange={handleName} value={imgname} />
```

Comment: I have spent close to an hour trying to figure this out. Thank you!!